# Human Detection output is faster and the feeds is Slow

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.8

This is my first time coding in image processing using python and OpenCV. My first project is using webcam to creates a Human Motion detection and display their walking speed in real-time monitoring feed and now the first step I have created a program to detect human motion but the feed is super slow and the results of the output video are very fast.  For example, I have running the program for about 1 minutes but the output video duration is only 7-10 seconds. I don't know how to fix this because I have try some adjustments like changing the waitKey() and the fps. I'm using HOG methods to detect human motion.

note : I'm using Logitech C270 with 30fps

this is my program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time

#initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

cv2.startWindowThread()

#open webcam video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#output will be written to output.avi
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_4.avi', fourcc, 18.0, (640,480))

frameCount = 0
start_time = time.time()

while(True):
    #capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.waitKey(30)

    #resizing for faster detection
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640,480))

    #using a greyscale picture, also for faster detection
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    #detect people in the image
    boxes, weights = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8))

    #returns the bounding boxes for the detected objects
    boxes = np.array([[x, y, x+w, y+h] for (x,y,w,h) in boxes])

    #final bounding boxes
    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB),
                      (0,255,0),2)

    #write the output video
    out.write(frame)

    #display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Human Detection',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#release the capture
cap.release()
#release the output
out.release()
#close the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(30)
```

Thank You.I hope you can help me.

Comment: hog person detection is slow, so without buffering and offline processing you probably will not reach the full 18 fps you assigned to the recorded video. This means you play a low fps viedeo with high fps, which shortens the video

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation, yet I still can't understand to make the fps video and the output synchronous. What code should I add or fix? Or if HOG method is slow what another method that could be used as Human Detection program so I could calculates the walking speed of pedestrian?

Comment: you could add a duplicate of an image for each dropped image. Or you could use multi-threading and record all images but only draw boxes in images which were processed by the detector.

Comment: How use this method? Can you give me any training or tutorial that I can I follow ? Because I'm really dark here in video/image processing.